# Don't understand why my code giving me an IndexError

Tags: python, list, statistics, average, standard-deviation

I am sorry if it is obvious what I am doing wrong, but I can't seem to figure why is my code giving me an index out of range error. I am a beginner, so take it easy please.

```
import statistics
z_alpha = [2,4,4,6,3]
z_beta = [5,6,8,9,2]
z_gamma = [4,6,6,8,2]
z_delta = [5,6,3,1,1]
def Stats():
     average_red = []
     st_dev =[]
     i = 0
     while i<=5:
          added_zs = z_alpha[i] + z_beta[i] + z_gamma[i] + z_delta[i]
          average_z = float(added_zs/4)
          average_red.append(average_z)
          standard = [z_alpha[i], z_beta[i], z_gamma[i], z_delta[i]]
          final_calc_dev = statistics.stdev(standard)
          st_dev.append(final_calc_dev)
          i+=1
     return average_red, st_dev

print(Stats()[0])
print(Stats()[1])
```

My error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/pedro/Desktop/Py projects/Wave_test.py", line 22, in <module>
    print(Stats()[0])
  File "c:/Users/pedro/Desktop/Py projects/Wave_test.py", line 13, in Stats
    added_zs = z_alpha[i] + z_beta[i] + z_gamma[i] + z_delta[i]
  IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: cause you only have five elements in your list, where the first one is indexed by `0` and last one by `4`. Remember that Python is a 0 index programming language

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `while` loop, you use `i<=5`. Python lists start at index `0`, which means the index values of a list with 5 elements would go from `0` to `4`. Replace `i<=5` with `i<5` and it should work.

Also, just a tip: a `for` loop would probably work better than a `while` loop in this situation. Like so:

```
for i in range(0,5):
    # code goes here
```

What this would do is iterate through all integers between `0` (inclusive) and `5` (exclusive), so it would go from `0` to `4`, which is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Using zip is probably a better option than fiddling with indices.

Use:

```
    for a,b,g,d in zip(z_alpha, z_beta, z_gamma, z_delta):
          added_zs = a + b + g + d
```